# How to Refer to the Current View Controller in the Code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm a new iOS developer with a simple question: I want to programmatically move from one view controller to the next, how do I write this code?

So far I have:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController;
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

I'm not even sure if this will work, ultimately, but my main question is "viewController" in line 4. The program doesn't know what that is. It is the name of my current view controller, but how do I set it up so that it knows what I mean by viewController?

As an aside, the above is part of an if/else statement that occurs and is connected to the NSUserDefaults class to make it such that the view controller I am referring to only loads if terms and conditions have not previously been accepted. Will that work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the simple answer: pass `self` when you want to pass the "current" object.

The more important consideration is: is that nav controller on screen? It's likely that your code won't do much unless you use a navigation controller which is (probably) the window's root view controller.

This is fairly easy to setup in your storyboard ("embed in"->"navigation controller") and then you don't need to instantiate it in code, you simply use self.navigationController (usually).

Comment: thank you. yes, I am using storyboards. I changed the code, but now I get an error that says "Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported." Which means what you told me works but the way I have it set up to do what I want is wrong.

Comment: Right, 'cause it looks like you are trying to push another instance of the same view controller (`self` in this context). Whenever you are in the "current" view controller and it has been embedded in a Nav Controller, there is no need to re-push it; I'm confident that makes reasonable sense and you can think through your app and what needs to happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would instantiate viewController just before you push it, so the program will know what it is. And, sure, you can have an if statement, and push this new view controller based on how the if statement evaluates.

I'm not sure about the code you wrote -- whether that's right depends on the structure of your app, and where you're doing this. Often, the navigation controller is made the root view controller of the window, and you set the navigation controller with a root view controller of its own when you create it